# Shortest Distance to Point from Parabola.

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

> Given the curve $y^2 = 4x$, find the point on the parabola that is the shortest distance to the point $(1,0)$

My work:

\begin{align}d &= \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2}\\
d &= \sqrt{(x-1)^2 +4x}\\
d &= \sqrt{x^2 - 2x + 1 + 4x}\\
d &= \sqrt{x^2 + 2x +1}\\
d &= x + 1\end{align}

At this point, taking the derivative would be useless. So, my question is: Is there a way using calculus that I can solve the above problem.

Comment: Hint for general problems like these: the point on the curve that minimizes the function giving the distance between the curve and your given point will be the same point that minimizes the *square* of this distance function.  In other words, the point that minimizes $d$ is precisely the point that minimizes $d^2$.  And this is convenient because you can avoid getting bogged down with the square root.  For instance, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828803/how-to-find-the-minimum-maximum-distance-of-a-point-from-elipse/828813#828813) for a worked example.

Comment: Of course, the square root didn't cause much hassle in this problem.  But it could've, given a problem with a different curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing your computation, we have

$$d=|x+1|.$$

But from $y^2=4x$ we draw that $x\ge0$ so that

$$|x+1|\ge1$$ and the equality is achieved by $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use Calculus? It follows from your computations that the shortest distance is reached when $x=0$ and that that distance is $1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how does it follow that $x = 0$? Is there a proper way to solve for $x$?

Comment: Since $4x=y^2\geqslant0$, you know that $x\geqslant0$. And, since $x\in[0,\infty)$ and since $d=x+1$, the minimal value that $d$ can take is $1$, which is obtained when $x=0$.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P(p^2, 2p)$ be a point on the parabola, and let $Q = (1,0)$. Then $PQ = \sqrt{(p^2 - 1)^2 + (2p-0)^2} = \sqrt{p^4 - 2p^2 + 1 + 4p^2} = \sqrt{(p^2 +1)^2} = p^2+1$.

Thus, $PQ = p^2 + 1$, so the minimum value of $PQ$ occurs at $p=0$. Thus, $P=(0,0)$, with $PQ=1$.

Comment: It seems we performed similar steps. Why did my steps not reach a solution but yours did?

Comment: @S.Sharma Your steps were close to the solution, but you did not check the range of $x$ (which in this question is $x \geq 0$, as $y^2 \geq 0$).

Answer (score 0):

You are right: $d=x+1$, but $x\ge0$. Hence the minimum is $d=1$ for $x=0$.

By the way: $(1,0)$ is the focus of the parabola, hence $d=x+1$ follows from the focus-directrix property.